# How do I code a Save button in WPF to save CSV Files after importing them in my application and editing it?

Tags: wpf, csv, save, export

Im using this Import Methode, and after editing the File in my application I want to have a button to save the File as a "new File" so the source doesnt get changed only a edited duplication is created.

```
//import button
        private void btn_Import_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //delete the filename from the textbox so they dont overlap
            tbx_FileName.Clear();
            
            //openFileDialog for file Import
            Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
            var result = dlg.ShowDialog();
            tbx_FileName.Text = dlg.FileName;

            DataContext = CSVTable.ReadFile(dlg.FileName);
        }
```

Comment: It is unclear what your question is exactly. Are you asking how to save the modified content to a new file?

Comment: yes, so i need an import and export function for the csv file in the application, i did already the import only need help how to export the file (best case with a button). The File is editable in my application @TamBui

Comment: Given that you want this to work with a button, see my submitted response.  If it works for you, please mark it as the answer.

Comment: @TamBui sadly it doesnt cause i get the error Argument 2: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string' and DataContext is beeing market

Answer (score 0):

```
//save button
        private void btn_Save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //saveFileDialog for file Save
            Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
            dlg.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
            dlg.Filter = "CSV file (*.csv)|*.csv|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
            var result = dlg.ShowDialog();
            if (result.HasValue && result.Value)
            {
                //Save the file, assuming the DataContext is plain text (i.e. string)
                File.WriteAllText(dlg.FileName, DataContext);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Im getting the error Argument 2: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string' and DataContext is beeing market. How to solve that? @TamBui

Comment: Please share your code for CSVTable.ReadFile in your original post.  I have absolutely no idea what your DataContext 'object' is.

Comment: If you have a `CSVTable.ReadFile` method, then check to see if you have a `CSVTable.SaveFile` method.  That should convert your 'object' to the correct format that you can save as a csv file.  Use that method in place of the `File.WriteAllText` method that I suggested.